# Oracle regexp_substr find "\", not "00" then [0-9a-fA-F]{2}

Tags: regex, oracle

In a list of values, denoted \nnnn where n is a hex digit I wish to find any occurence not starting with \00 and return the "\" and all 4 digits

ex: \004e\2029\00a3  -> \2029

as far as i have gotten:

```
select regexp_substr('\004e\2029\00a3', '\\^00[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}') from dual -- returns null

select regexp_substr('\004e\2029\00a3', '\\[^0]{2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}') from dual -- returns null, but would match \2129, both leading chars not "0"
```

should I create the whole regex twice with a "|" and check first for ^0 in the first position, then check for ^0 in the second ?

this works, but is it not terribly ineffective?

```
'\\([^0][0-9A-Fa-f]{3}|[0-9A-Fa-f][^0][0-9A-Fa-f]{2})'
```

Do you have a neat solution ?

Comment: Is it known beforehand that the string is a concatenation of hex representations (that is, a backslash followed by four hex digits)? In that case you don't need to check for `[0-9A-Fa-f]` and the regexp can be a lot simpler (and faster).

Comment: Instead of `[0-9A-Fa-f]` you can also use `[[:xdigit:]]`

Comment: Thanks, that makes it easier to read

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this - if it is known beforehand that the input strings are all concatenations of four-digit escaped hex values.

```
with 
  test_data as (
    select 101 as id, '\004e\2029\00a3' as str from dual union all
    select 103      , '\23ab\687a\0032'        from dual
  )
select id, level as ord,
       regexp_substr(str, '\\(.[^0]|[^0].)..', 1, level) as token
from   test_data
connect by level <= regexp_count(str, '\\(.[^0]|[^0].)..')
       and prior id = id
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
;


        ID        ORD  TOKEN         
----------  ---------  ---------------
       101          1  \2029          
       103          1  \23ab          
       103          2  \687a
```

Comment: They are, at least the ones I'm looking for. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '\004e\2029\00a3' from dual union
  3     select '\23ab\687a\0032' from dual
  4    )
  5  select '\' || regexp_substr(col, '[^\]+', 1, column_value) result
  6  from test,
  7       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  8                           connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '\\')
  9                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 10  where substr(regexp_substr(col, '[^\]+', 1, column_value), 1, 2) <> '00';

RESULT
----------------
\2029
\23ab
\687a
```

Comment: clever, thank you. I was rather looking for an improved regex by itself, but I'll keep your option in my toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for inputs and suggestions. My working regex is now a ghost in my machine, though being frowned upon until I'm sure it is not too costly or perhaps I can optimize it.